# Arduino IDE swithcing url's

Tags: html, arduino

I have been using two ESP8266 for home automation. I just want to ask how to switch from these two wifi module simultaneously. I have problem in switching from 192.168.1.103 to my other wifi module 192.169.1.101.

This is the code from 192.168.1.103.

```
<p><a href='//192.168.0.101'><button>CHANGE</button></a></p>
```

Every time I do this, it redirects me to this url "https://192.168.0.103/192.168.0.101"

Comment: If you want to open `https://192.168.0.101/`, you can just change the `href` attribute to `https://192.168.1.101/`.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking. Can you please edit the question to clarify the issue you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to:

```
<p><a href='http://192.168.0.101'><button>CHANGE</button></a></p>
```